# maximum size of data we can ‘GET’ by using adapters

Tags: blockchain, chainlink

What is the maximum size of data we can ‘GET’ by using adapters within chainlink? The data I am planning to use maybe JSON data, an array, or a simple text file.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no restriction on the size of the GET itself. It's then [what you do with it](https://docs.chain.link/docs/tasks/) after where there are restrictions. In the past, responses back on-chain have been limited to a single value (integer, 32byte string etc), so you'd then have to choose or 'strip' out a value from the result of the HTTP GET, then parse and return it on-chain, however, Chainlink now supports [multi-word responses](https://docs.chain.link/docs/multi-variable-responses/)

Comment: The data I am planning to use maybe JSON data, an array, or a simple text file. so the file of data may not have any limit right?